# Set class or struct type as parameter

Tags: ios, swift

Currently, I'm working with stream data. This is my code ported from Obj-C:

```
func readInt8() -> Int {
    var temp = Int8()
    //get value for temp
    return Int(temp)
}

func readInt64() -> Int {
    var temp = Int()
    //get value for temp
    return temp
}

func readFloat32() -> Float {
    var temp = Float32()
    //get value for temp
    return temp
}
```

Here's my attempt:

```
func read<T: SignedIntegerType>(type: T.Type) -> Int {
    //error: Missing argument for parameter 'integerLiteral' in call
    var temp = T()
    //getting value for temp requires it to be initialized
}
```

How can I make these functions generic ? Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this gist - seems similar to what you're trying to do: https://gist.github.com/davepeck/495ea71f815ce292d6e0

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've done so far:

```
func readInt<T: SignedIntegerType>() -> T {
    return T(0)
}

func readFloat<T: FloatingPointType>() -> T {
    return T(0)
}

var a: Double = readFloat() //0.0
var b: Int32 = readInt() //0
```

could be good. Int(), Int8(), Float() do the same as they creates a new variable, and initializes to zero. So if you write T(0) explicitly, it would do the same.